# Netbeans hibernate pdf report

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans, report

I can't pdf report in netbeans with hibernate connection. I have a jsp page and a submit button which is supposed to read the database with hibernate connection and create pdf report for that. I can handle manually without any problem with jasper reports, ireport etc. So I can see what I want, but I want to do so that when I click on the submit button, it dynamically reads database and then converts the jrxml file to pdf. Also, I don't want it to use beans. Just a simple pdf creation with hibernate. Is that possible? Can anyone help me out with that?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly If you write code or error more accurately we can answer.What is version of hibernate?I tried it with hibernate 3.8 but doesn't work cause jasper report's authors explained thus **"We are currently supporting Hibernate 3.3.2.GA. Same version as JasperReports and JasperReports Server. There is also a dedicated library that you can add for compiling code in the "Build Path" preference page.
Unfortunately we currently don't support the co-existence of multiple Hibernate versions.
We will probably work on this in the nearly future."** http://community.jaspersoft.com/jaspersoft-studio/issues/3802

Otherwise you can follow these steps;
http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/hibernate/